# WordPress get category ID to Array

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have this code in `category.php` and I want to show posts from the category in which I am, "`$cat`" and the category referred to `id` 63. I wrote something but do not want to work :/

```
<?php
$cat->term_id;
$my_query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(63, $cat),
            'operator' => 'AND'
        )
    )
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($my_query_args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Can someone tell me why do not incur the currently displayed category to `$cat`?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
echo $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
```

This will give you the current category id. 
Now place the below query before the starting of wordpress loop in category.php

```
query_posts( 'cat='.$cat_id);
```

If thats normal category you dont want to make it complex with too many args. This will work dynamically by checking your current category id.

Answer (score 1):

may be you mess with 'field' arguments in your tac_query.

```
'field' => 'term_id',
```

field- Select taxonomy term by. Possible values are 'term_id', 'name', 'slug' or 'term_taxonomy_id'. Default value is 'term_id'.

Answer (score 0):

probably your `$cat` variable is an object. Try to change `'terms' => array( 63, $cat ),` into `'terms' => array( 63, $cat->ID ),` or `'terms' => array( 63, $cat->id ),`

Answer (score 0):

try this set your cat id or name at cat =..

```
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=10' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<ul>
<li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

<ul><li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```